# dipatch_async releases local variable

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I did not find any suitable answers on the web, so I post my question here.

```
__block int test = 1;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    test = 2;
});
NSLog(@"%i",test);
```

This code will result in console message "1".

```
__block NSString *test = @"no";
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    test = @"yes";
});
NSLog(@"%@",test);
```

This code will result in console message "no".

Why is it so? I thought that __block identifier should solve all problems in this case.
My hypothesis is that local variable was copied and code inside block hadn't actually modify anything outside itself.

How can I modify local variables inside dispatch_async?

Sorry if it is a noob question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are dispatching **asynchronously** to the main queue.

The `dispatch_async` returns before the block is executed (coincidentally).

To underscore how non-deterministic concurrent programming can be:

Note that your `NSLog()` might sometimes see the new value maybe once in a very blue moon.  You might not ever see it in your debugging environment, but some customer might encounter that behavior 3 years from now on a system configuration that doesn't exist today.

To fix?

`dispatch_sync()` thereby ensuring that your background queue and the main queue are effectively acting like a less efficient single serial queue.

... or ...

Use some kind of synchronization construct to message from the main queue back to your local queue when the operation is done.   I.e.:

```
dispatch_async(otherQueue, ^{
     ... do something ...;
     dispatch_async(firstQueue, ^{
          done(calculatedValue);
     };
};
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now I can understand the problem.

Comment: Excellent!   **Concurrency is hard** is a mantra that every programmer should take to heart!

Answer (score 1):

You are dispatching setting test asynchronously, meaning your NSLog statement is going to fire before the block.

You would have to do it this way, or change it to a dispatch_sync.

```
__block NSString *test = @"no";
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  test = @"yes";
  NSLog(@"%@",test);
});
```

If you need to do something on a background thread and then pop it back onto the main thread, just do the following:

```
__block NSString *test = @"no";
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   test = @"setting Testing in the background";
   NSLog(@"Printing from the background:%@",test);
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    test = @"Setting Test on the main thread";
    NSLog(@"Logging test on the main thread:%@",test);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling dispatch_async. Although you are executing the code on the main thread, it is still not determined wether the code "test = @"yes" gets executed before the "NSLog(@"%@",test);" code.

If you use dispatch_sync it will work as expexted.

Comment: Yes, true, I just wanted to show the difference. Please look at bbum's code example for how to also keep it async ;-)